# How to (true by pass) or switch on off your effects pedal board BOss GT100 to get original guitar amp sound

Tags: dynamics

I want to be able to go directly to my guitar amp sound which is a Roland JC120 and or a Fender Bassbreaker guitar amp. I use a BOSS GT100 Pedal effect board.

This GT100 when switched correctly does give you a similar amp sound but it is not my true guitar sound.

When stage performing, what device/switch pedal should I use so I can turn off my Boss GT 100 sound and then go directly to my original guitar amp sound and then turn off the amp sound to go to back to my GT100 effects board in between a song.

I have tried several bypass switches to no avail. They give me a similar sound but not the same. Is it that our technology is not there yet and I am just spinning my wheels to get that crisp original sound from my guitar amp?

Comment: I have tried to edit for clarity, but still am not sure what you are asking - a bypass will not give you any 'sound' - it simply switches between the effect and clean. So if your bypass switch has GT100 on the one side and your amp on the other, you will get whatever sound your amp gives when you switch directly to it. Can you please edit your question to explain what your problem is.

Comment: @DrMayhem I think he's saying that the 'clean' mode of the bypass still doesn't sound as good as going straight in to the amp - is that right Eduardo?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand. If that is the case, the answer is simple - buy a true bypass pedal :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you require is an A B true bypass pedal

[image]

Comment: A true bypass pedal (or true bypass looper) and an A/B pedal are different things. Usually a true bypass looper can be used *as* an A/B pedal - but a simple A/B pedal (as illustrated) can't be used as a bypass pedal.